# FileNotFoundError despite file existing

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, filenotfounderror

This is the function that uses a file to return some parameters

```
def load_network_params(agent_name: str, env_name: str,
                        network_root_folder: str = 'jax-models') -> flax.core.FrozenDict:

    filePathString=network_root_folder+r"/"+agent_name+r"/"+env_name+r"/2"
    fileNameStr=r"ckpt.199"
    fileString=os.path.join(filePathString,fileNameStr)
    with open(fileString, 'rb') as file:
     # file processing irrelevant to error
        })
    return network_params
```

This is the way the function was subsequently used:

```
from dataset import *
generate_dataset(r"dqn", r"Breakout", 10_000, network_root_folder=r"C:/Users/jk5g19/Documents/Year3IP/scripts/jax")
```

Edit: Basically the generate_dataset calls load_network_parameter, I tried to cut down the amount of code shared, so that people would get less confused. This is the Minimum Viable product.

```
def generate_dataset(agent_name: str, env_name: str, dataset_size: int, num_envs: int = 20, epsilon: float = 0.1,
                     network_root_folder: str = 'jax-models') -> Tuple[onp.ndarray, onp.ndarray, onp.ndarray,
                                                                       onp.ndarray, int]:

    num_actions = gym.make(f'{env_name}NoFrameskip-v0').action_space.n

    images_obs_dataset = onp.zeros((dataset_size, 84, 84, 4))
    ram_obs_dataset = onp.zeros((dataset_size, 128))
    q_values_dataset = onp.zeros((dataset_size, num_actions))
    action_dataset = onp.zeros(dataset_size)

    network_def, network_args = get_network_def(agent_name, num_actions)
    network_params = load_network_params(agent_name, env_name, network_root_folder=network_root_folder)

    return images_obs_dataset, ram_obs_dataset, q_values_dataset, action_dataset, episodes_run
```

When I output the filestring and copy and paste it into the file explorer the desired file can be accessed. I used raw strings for the path and experimented with double back slashes and forward slashes.

I also added a test.txt file in the path too, the file path did not work hence it rules out the file type causing issues with open().

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yXBl.png)

Comment: If interpreter says FileNotFound then there is something you ovelook. Print `fileString` and confirm the path is indeed correct. Also, you show `load_network_params()` code, that takes 3 params and then call different function `generate_dataset()` that takes 4 params. Include the relevant code as well as full traceback you get.

Comment: What's the purpose of calling `os.listdir()` if you just ignore the result?

Comment: To add to what @GregHewgill said, I don't think calling `listdir` with a filepath works, it should raise an error (unless `ckpt.199` is a folder)

Comment: You are iterating over os.listdir() but not using any of its return values

Comment: @gionni shall I remove listdir

Comment: Again, you show the code for `load_network_params()` and how you call totally different function `generate_dataset()`. Show the relevant code as well as the full traceback you get.

Comment: I made an edit detailing generate_dataset and how load_network parameters ties into it

Comment: @JayantKalyan, you should remove it because it should raise an exception, and also because you are not really using the loop, at least not in the code you showed. Other than that, could you share the complete filepath you paste in the file explorer?

Comment: C:/Users/jk5g19/Documents/Year3IP/scripts/jax/dqn/Breakout/2/ckpt.199 @gionni

Comment: @gionni removed the listdir, but the issue still persists

Comment: yes it is, I have shared a screenshot of the error on my latest update @gionni

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux, is that correct? The problem might stem from there. Have you tried opening a different file? Does it work?

Comment: @gionni yes I tried to open a textfile in the same filepath and it did not seem to work either PS: I have added another tag for wsl due to your suggestion

Comment: @gionni it is working now, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for my dataset_setup.py I was supposed to do this:

```
from dataset import *
generate_dataset(r"dqn", r"Breakout", 10_000, network_root_folder=r"/mnt/c/Users/jk5g19/Documents/Year3IP/scripts/jax")
```

This was because I was using WSL. Massive thank you to @gionni for helping me come to this conclusion.